# Can I pass in a member variable for an Android Service to use?

Tags: android, service, android-manifest

I would like to reuse some service layer code in another project.  I do want to be able to change one of the member variables the service uses, without having different service code.  I don't see how this can be done as I don't "create" the service; the manifest and the system do that.  Thus I can't pass something in a constructor.

I have a hard time finding the write words to ask this question, so perhaps a quick example is best.  I have a service, such as:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MyCommunicatorListener {

ICommunicator _comm = new BlueToothCommunicator(); // great for project 1, not for project 2!

public void shutUpCommunicator()  // example of using communicator
{
    _comm.Shutup();
}

// MyCommunicatorListener methods
@Override
public void onPageReceived(Page page) {  // example of listening to communicator
    Log.d(TAG,"onPageReceived");

}
}  // class greatly simplified...
```

All works well.  The service is started my virtue of the fact that it's declared in the manifest:

```
 <service android:name="com.acme.servicelayer.MyService" android:process=":remote" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.acme.servicelayer.MyService" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I'd like to keep this service code and reuse it another project.  In the other project, I don't want to use:

```
ICommunicator _comm = new BlueToothCommunicator(); // great for project 1, not for project 2!
```

I want to use:
    ICommunicator _comm = new WiFiCommunicator(); // great for project 2, not for project 
1!
How can I do this and keep the same code base?  Is there someway to pass arguments through the manifest?
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: boot_completed is a broadcast. a service will not receive it. home is an activity category. a service will not receive it.

Comment: Check the intent onStartCommand and/or onBind and adjust your code from the intent.

Comment: can you decompose some or all of WifiCommunicator into a parcel?  If so, you could attach that data to an intent and use onStartCommand/onBind to configure or re-configure the *Communicator field of the service as needed